# How can I fix 404 error importing css on GitHub Pages?

Tags: html, github, travis-ci, github-pages

I currently have the following Git Repository:
https://github.com/SebastianGode/ansible-collection-cloud/tree/gh-pages
And the GitHub Page link:
https://sebastiangode.github.io/ansible-collection-cloud/

The problem is that GitHub Pages will only solve the index.html and will throw an 404 for all required css and image stuff:
[image]

As the documentation is getting automatically generated by a travis-ci pipeline it's probably impossible to change paths, but as it works when hosted it locally it also should work on GitHub pages.

Is there any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed it.

GitHub has Jekyll running behind it which will mess up special paths (here the underscore paths). You can disable jekyll by just creating a `.nojekyll` file in the root directory of the branch. If you use travis-CI for something like that and run a tox script just call the command `touch {toxinidir}/.nojekyll`

This will result in a working website for me.

Comment: I faced exactly the same problem with Hugo, you are the hero!